# SQL prefix for multiple insert/update

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I have prepared one script that `updates/insert` new values into few tables. Instead of using hardcoded values, I want to use prefix that will allow me to refer to this schema as variable.

Example as per below. Instead of using SKC I want to use for example value like abc

```
insert into SKC.type_table (TYPE_CD, STATUS_CD, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, UPD_USER_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE)


insert into SKC.type_df (TYPE_CD, LANGUAGE_CD, TYPE_DESCRIPTION, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, UPD_USER_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
```

Comment: Do you know all the possible target tables upfront? In standard SQL identifiers should be known before the actual query execution, because Oracle [builds the execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-1B95E60C-99C5-446D-9C6B-5D16EFE59ACF) and does semantic check. So you have to prepare your statements somwhere outside the execution context: be it external language or PL/SQL block with `execute immediate` doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes I actually do. Script does have all table names upfront.

Comment: How about `alter session set current_schema = SKC;`

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the table names upfront, you may use [multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423):

> ```
> create table templ (
>   id int
> );
> ```

> ```
> create procedure generate_tabs(num int)
> as
> begin
>   for i in 1..num loop
>     execute immediate 'create table t_' || to_char(i, 'TM9')
>     || ' as select * from templ where 1 = 0';
>   
>   end loop;
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> begin
>   generate_tabs(5);
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> insert all
>   when tab_name = 1 then into t_1
>     values(val)
>   when tab_name = 2 then into t_2
>     values(val)
>   when tab_name = 3 then into t_3
>     values(val)
>   when tab_name = 4 then into t_4
>     values(val)
>   when tab_name = 5 then into t_5
>     values(val)
> select
>   level as tab_name,
>   level as val
> from dual
> connect by level < 5
> ```

> ```
> select 't_1' as src, t_1.*
> from t_1
> union all
> select 't_2' as src, t_2.*
> from t_2
> union all
> select 't_3' as src, t_3.*
> from t_3
> union all
> select 't_4' as src, t_4.*
> from t_4
> union all
> select 't_5' as src, t_5.*
> from t_5
> ```
>
> ```
> SRC | ID
> :-- | -:
> t_1 |  1
> t_2 |  2
> t_3 |  3
> t_4 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f62521173b6909f43f76e9d7f07a43f4)*

Answer (score 0):

Remove all schema names from your script and set the default schema name before running the script. For example, if you're running your scripts in SQL*Plus:

```
alter session set current_schema = abc;
@your_script.sql
alter session set current_schema = skc;
@your_script.sql
```